# Gnome Shell freezes when using external USB drives

Tags: 11.10, freeze, gnome, usb-drive

Sometimes my system freezes when I use my external USB HDD (Western Digital 500GB). I am using a freshly upgraded Ubuntu 11.10 installation.

The freeze is not reproducable but always happens right after I unplug the device. The last time it happened right after I clicked the "Eject" Button in the Gnome Shell notification that appears when you plug in an external drive.

It is a real freeze, I have to hard reset the system when it happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this issue strictly with GNOME Shell? Have you tried reproducing these freezes under Unity?

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at [this Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze) on troubleshooting freezes, and possibly report a bug for it.

Comment: It has never ever happened before I started to use gnome-shell. But I can't be a 100% sure that it is strictly a gnome shell issue since I switched to gnome shell 1 day after I upgraded to oneiric. So it may have something to do with the upgrade.. When I'm back home I will give my best to reproduce it in gome-shell / unity.

Comment: Vote to close as this seems to be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/878294).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the launchpad bugs - Upgrading to 3.0.6 kernel should solve the issue. Deb packages are available from;
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.0.6-oneiric/

Installation Guide (for amd64)

1. Download the kernel headers package;

   http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.0.6-oneiric/linux-headers-3.0.6-030006_3.0.6-030006.201110050043_all.deb
2. And the appropriate package for your architecture;

   http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.0.6-oneiric/linux-headers-3.0.6-030006-generic_3.0.6-030006.201110050043_amd64.deb
3. And the accompanying compiled kernel;

   http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.0.6-oneiric/linux-image-3.0.6-030006-generic_3.0.6-030006.201110050043_amd64.deb
4. Install the files in the same order
5. In the terminal run: `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot and select the kernel from the bootloader menu

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to replicate the system freeze when using nautilus to un-mount a 1tb WD Passport.

I can safely remove it by calling

```
sudo umount /media/<MountPoint>
sudo /usr/local/sbin/suspend-usb-device.sh /dev/<disk> -v
```

The suspend script is [available on github](https://github.com/bond711/suspend-usb-device/blob/patch-1/suspend-usb-device)

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I'll check it out in a few hours.

Comment: What is interesting is I still get a freeze on my server using this script, but not on my desktop o_0 - so its not likely to be gnome related (server is headless)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug. It happens to me on Unity too. I tried the script suspend-usb-device but my system got frozen again.

Opened bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/878294